# How can I fuse a lot of cubes?

Tags: modeling

So, I made a mesh with a lot of cubes ( I've created a cube, and copied it, pasted it to make figures ), And, when I've done it, I tried to smooth it, but it looks wierd because it's made with a lot of cubes, so a lot of faces, I already tried Ctrl + J, but faces remain, Is there anyway to fuse those lot of faces in one?

Comment: please upload your .blend

Comment: Hi Carl, do you mind clarifying your goal?  Would you like the cubes smoothed, and that is all?  Are the cubes separate objects?

Comment: You need to delete the inside faces of the cubes. Change selection type to faces and select and delete the unwanted faces.

Comment: You could try Boolean operations, but the way you are doing things is probably bound to give trouble sooner or later. You should learn to model properly, try watching some tutorials

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you need joining cubes without inner vertices.

You can do it in second using Bool Tool addon:

Just select all cubes, (one of them must be active) in BoolTool menu click on "Brush" -> "Union" -> "Apply All" - done

[Download Bool Tool](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/BoolTool)