# How can I fuse those blocks?

Tags: modeling

So, I made this mesh with a lot of cubes

[image]

Is there any way to fuse them (besides <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>)?
Because when I smooth them, it smooths all the blocks and it looks weird

Comment: You could use CTRL + P to parent them to the last object selected. I frequently add an Empty to parent to.

Comment: This appears to be exactly the same as your other question. If you need to give additional information please use the 'edit' link below your other question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question ( http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/how-can-i-fuse-a-lot-of-cubes) . The original question was closed due to lack of information, but it can be re-opened if additional information is added. Please read: [How can I reopen a question?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) . Also take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works.

Comment: I give you solution here, and I'm sure it work, because I try it. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/how-can-i-fuse-a-lot-of-cubes  Did you try it? It work?

Comment: You have to do this by hand.  Also, the moderators put your question on hold for a reason!  I'm going to flag this.